# How to develop something as a group in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My friend and I were searching for already built-in features in Eclipse or plugins that allow you to develop code in a group, or to be more specific, in a pair.
I found only a single plugin that provides such features, however it is quite hard to install.

Are there any simple solutions for Eclipse, or should I use a different editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Git/GitHub or a similar form of version control. I am pretty sure Eclipse has built in support for Git.

Comment: There is actually a git view in eclipse. I'd recommand github for a first try, it's the most commonly used.